# Transform square matrix into 1D array with NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Let's say I have a square matrix with 20 lines and 20 columns. Using NumPy, what should I do to transform this matrix into a 1D array with a single line and 400 columns (that is, 20.20 = 400, all in one line)?

So far, I've tried:

1) `array = np.ravel(matrix)`

2) `array = np.squeeze(np.asarray(matrix))`

But when I print `array`, it's still a square matrix.

Comment: Try `array = matrix.flatten()`

Comment: or `matrix.reshape(-1,)`

Comment: Also try `np.reshape()` it should work(more detail [https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html]).

Comment: If you're using a numpy matrix, then switch to an ordinary ndarray. The matrix object is deprecated. `array = matrix.ravel()` should work if matrix is an ndarray.

Comment: If `ravel` doesn't work, then there's something unusual about `matrix`.  Tell us its `shape`, `dtype`, and whether it is `np.matrix` or not.

Comment: `matrix` is built from a `for` loop. There's an array of arrays, where the parent array is composed of arrays with coordinates. The `for` loop makes some calculations with the elements of the child arrays, and the result is put into a square matrix.

Comment: `array = matrix.reshape((1,400))` worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the reshape method:
`array = matrix.reshape((1,400))`.
This works for both Numpy Array and Matrix types.

UPDATE: As sacul noted, `matrix.reshape(-1)` is more general in terms of dimensions.